# Assigning <script> tag to javascript variable and insert it to html

Tags: javascript

I have this code that will check if an element exist on a page, and then execute the script.

```
<script>
  var interval = setInterval(nodeLoaded, 500)
  var dynamicScriptOne = "<script src='https://www.source-here.com'></script>";
  var dynamicScriptTwo = "<script> console.log('log here')</script>";

  // Check if node is loaded
  function nodeLoaded() {
    var node = document.querySelector('.node-container')
    if (node){
        ******************************************** 
          INSERT THE DYNAMIC SCRIPT VARIABLE 
          "dynamicScriptOne" and "dynamicScriptTwo" 
          TO HTML PAGE HERE 
        ************************************************

        // Clear Interval Function when node is loaded
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }
</script>
```

I have a web app, and users are adding their scripts from the backend. And they can choose the event of firing the script. Like "onEnter", "onExit" and "onLoad"

The "onLoad" event will fire the scripts that they have added from the backend when the page was fully loaded. Because there is a delay, something like .5 seconds to 1 second before the page is rendered.

Is there a way to inject those variables to HTML inside the javascript function?

Answer (score 1):

If you trust the incoming input, consider appending the script to the `node`, but then it will not run. So then you can take the `innerHTML` of the script tags and then run it through `eval`. HOWEVER, **eval is unsafe if you do not know what your script is** and should be avoided if possible.